# sudo: cd: command not found when trying to get to /var/log/apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and am having issues getting to the log files in /var/log/apache2

I can `cd` to most other places (I haven't tried every single file, obviously) but when I try to get to the above directory, I get the error message `sudo: cd: command not found`

... I've just tried something else and I can't `cd` when used in conjunction with `sudo`. I can use `sudo` when doing things like `apt-get` but it seems I can't change directory when using `sudo`.

I haven't been on this server for a while but I know I used to be able to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On most systems, `cd` isn't a program, it's a shell command, so you can't use `sudo` to run it.  Try `sudo -i` to get an interactive shell then cd into that directory.

Comment: That's not 100% true - on some systems there is a `cd` in /usr/bin as well as the shell built-in, and that's what `sudo` will invoke.  However, even when that's true, it won't do you any good because once the `sudo` command finishes and exits you're back at the directory you started at.

Comment: How would a `/usr/bin/cd` command function? Doesn't the "it won't do you any good" part apply even *without* sudo?

Comment: Hah! Learn something new every day. @mattdm: Apparently systems with a cd program have it so that scripts can test if you can change into a directory or not (by checking its return value for errors) http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.solaris/2006-07/msg00496.html

Answer (score 0):

Supplemental to DerfK's answer;

Before I discovered `sudo -i`, I'd use `sudo ls /var/log/abcd` to identify the files in such a directory, and then read the files more directly.

Not the cleanest way,... but there's always more than one way to skin a cat..